# RxJS: How to import Just

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I'd like to use RxJS's `just`.
What I need it for is `Observable.just(null)`, which can't be done with `Observable.from()`.

I'm trying

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/just';
```

But it's not present in where it should be - `node_modules/rxjs/add/operator`, so this fails to compile.

How can I add this operator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That depends on the version of Rx.js:

- [4.0](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) includes a [`.just`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/return.md) method;
- [5.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) doesn't. Instead, use the [`.of`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of) method.

Like this:

```
Rx.Observable.of(null).forEach(x => console.log(x))
```